# Why does this Pi approximation become less accurate?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, montecarlo

The code included below calculates a pi approximation in Java using a Monte Carlo method. As expected, the answer (very) gradually improves, but when the main loop terminates the answer is always worse than the results during the run. Why?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;


public class PiMonte
{
  private static final int MAX_PTS = 500000;

  private static final BigDecimal BD100 = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);
  private static final BigDecimal BD10 = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);
  private static final BigDecimal BD4 = BigDecimal.valueOf(4);

  private static final BigDecimal PI = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI);
  

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random rand = new Random();

    BigDecimal circlePts = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal totalPts = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal piEstimate = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    BigDecimal err = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal eps = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);  // percentage

    MathContext mc = new MathContext(20);

    System.out.println("Math.PI: \t" + Math.PI);
    System.out.println("PI Estimation");

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PTS; i++) {
      double x = rand.nextDouble()*2-1;  // in the range [-1,1]
      double y = rand.nextDouble()*2-1;

      if ((x*x + y*y) <= 1)  // inside circle
        circlePts = circlePts.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
      totalPts = totalPts.add(BigDecimal.ONE);

      piEstimate = circlePts.multiply(BD4).divide(totalPts, mc);
      err = piEstimate.subtract(PI).multiply(BD100).divide(PI, mc).abs();

      if (err.compareTo(eps) < 0) {
        System.out.println(" Step " + i + ": \t" + piEstimate + 
                               " < " + eps + "%; " + format(err) + "%");
        eps = eps.divide(BD10);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("\nEnd " + MAX_PTS + ": \t" + piEstimate + 
                                           " and " + format(err) + "%");

  } /* main */


  public static String format(BigDecimal num) 
  {
    DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.##########");
    return df.format(num);
  }

}
```

The originally code used doubles, and displayed the same problem, which I thought was due to rounding. That's why I rewrote the code using BigDecimals. I've run the program with many different stopping values for `MAX_PTS`, and the accuracy of the calculation varies (as you'd expect). What surprises me is how poor the final result is; always a lot less accurate than the best results during execution. The following output illustrates my point:

```
> java PiMonte
Math.PI:        3.141592653589793
PI Estimation
 Step 2:        1.3333333333333333333 < 100%; 57.5586818422%
 Step 20:       2.8571428571428571429 < 10%; 9.0543182332%
 Step 107:      3.1111111111111111111 < 1%; 0.9702576317%
 Step 111:      3.1428571428571428571 < 0.1%; 0.0402499435%
 Step 190:      3.1413612565445026178 < 0.01%; 0.0073655967%
 Step 1327:     3.1415662650602409639 < 0.001%; 0.000839973%
 Step 24174:    3.1415925542916235781 < 0.0001%; 0.0000031608%
 Step 87878:    3.1415924168458903720 < 0.00001%; 0.0000075358%
 Step 186181:   3.1415926351634422232 < 0.000001%; 0.0000005865%

End 500000:     3.143968 and 0.0756096245%
```

In response to the comments, I increased MAX_PTS to 500000000 and ran the code again. Typical output was:

```
Math.PI:        3.141592653589793
PI Estimation
 Step 0:        4 < 100%; 27.3239544735%
 Step 83:       3.4285714285714285714 < 10%; 9.1348181202%
 Step 157:      3.1645569620253164557 < 1%; 0.7309766404%
 Step 158:      3.1446540880503144654 < 0.1%; 0.0974484855%
 Step 274:      3.1418181818181818182 < 0.01%; 0.0071787865%
 Step 5740:     3.1416129594147361087 < 0.001%; 0.0006463545%
 Step 45269:    3.1415948751932847360 < 0.0001%; 0.0000707158%
 Step 71415:    3.1415929203539823009 < 0.00001%; 0.0000084914%
 Step 131051:   3.1415926502457039954 < 0.000001%; 0.0000001064%
 Step 131955:   3.1415926520961532632 < 1E-7%; 0.0000000475%
 Step 4182829:  3.1415926537774664521 < 1E-8%; 0.000000006%
 Step 47075584:         3.1415926536016493475 < 1E-9%; 0.0000000004%
 Step 196187169:        3.1415926535868782857 < 1E-10%; 0.0000000001%
 Step 345802403:        3.1415926535895337500 < 1E-11%; 0%

End 500000000:  3.141660976 and 0.0021747699%
```

The error seems to converge on an average of 0.002%. I'd like to understand why that is.

Here's a plot of err*10000 vs the number of iterations. Each point is recorded every 10,000 steps up to 500 M.
[image]

Comment: For one thing, `Math.PI` is a double, so it is an approximation and the BigDecimal could get closer. I'm not sure if that is the case. Another thing, you only print out on certain loops when err < eps.  If you were to plot it you probably find the err isn't decreasing monotonically, but is fluctuating around some value that is decreasing.

Comment: Not only is `Math.PI` a `double`, `rand.nextDouble()` and the entire circle calculation is done with `double` precision too. So it’s pointless to pretend a higher accuracy by using `BigDecimal` *afterwards*.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem since the random numbers are only being used to increment counters. Also, the calculation result is accurate *during* execution, but disappointing at the end.

Comment: How do you determine that your “calculation result is accurate during execution”? How can you even claim that after [admitting that it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885245/why-does-this-pi-approximation-become-less-accurate#comment133852437_75885463)?

Comment: Accurate in the sense of being close to Java's value for PI.

Comment: Referring to user16320675: doesn't Monte Carlo rely on the law of large numbers, which means that the piEstimate value will always move towards the 'correct' answer (barring rounding errors)?

Comment: You are not “accurate in the sense of being close to Java's value for PI”. You already admitted that you get the same graph as shown in the answer, just wiggling up and down rather than converging. Some values happening to be closer to `Math.PI` than others is not a prove for accuracy. That’s just chance. I could take arbitrary random numbers between three and four and some of them will happen to be closer to PI. I could even get exactly PI by chance. Repeated evaluation will only converge as much as the actual random number generator and the accuracy of the calculation allow.

Comment: I think, the biggest problem here is that you are citing the “law of large numbers” while 500,000 is not a large number at all. It easily fits into an `int` counter, as demonstrated by your `for` loop. As said, your use of `BigDecimal` is a big distraction. You are as close as one can expect after only 500,000 iterations. You have the wrong expectation because *some* error values happened to be smaller. Talk again about “large numbers” after checking 500,000,000 and 500,000,000,000 iterations (note that even that number doesn’t require `BigDecimal`, optimize the loop to reduce waiting time).

Comment: You should be able to estimate the expected variance of the prediction based on the number of samples taken. Any particular measurement doesn't change, but if you took an ensemble of measurements, then you should see a decrease in average error with an increase in N. Also, this technique creates a biased random walk with a step size of 1/N. Which means the value can get stuck far away from the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't decreasing monotonically. It should be decreasing on average though.

Here is the error for a sample run.

[image]

If you zoom in.

[image]

You should be able to estimate the variance after N steps. You're essentially taking a random walk with a step size of 1/N. One way to improve the accuracy is to compare the values of different simulation runs.

[image]

That image shows the average error and the std deviation of the error from the value obtained with ensemble of 10 simulations.

[image]

That is the zoomed in version. You can see the variance decreases with more steps. But, the actual error for any given simulation might not be less. It *could* be though.

This way also helps you see how accurate your estimate is. In your example you *know* Math.PI, but if you were to do use this technique to solve something you don't know, then sampling an ensemble of simulation runs shows the value converge to an average value.

Comment: From the looks of it, I feel like the estimate has sort of almost stabilised after some point. Perhaps it's just that the rate of the convergence is slower the longer you do this?

Comment: I added some plotting code that added the piEstimate value to a graph every 10,000 steps, and obtained a graph similar to yours. I continued the graph up to 5 million, and the estimate didn't improve at all. The error seems to converge to a value and stays there.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the err value. I plot err*10000 against steps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop you only report these steps where `err` is smaller than `eps` but in many cases this is not the case. In the end you just report the final step. Here, also `err` is **not** smaller than `eps`, hence the worse approximation.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, my code uses the Monte Carlo method which relies on the law of large numbers. In particular, that means that the piEstimate value will always move towards the 'correct' answer (barring rounding errors).

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to everyone for helping me to understand what was going on. As Holger pointed out, my printing of `piEstimate` during the execution is not very useful since these are just random values that happen to be close to pi. I should have focused instead on how the error value decreases over time, which brings those random values on average closer to the true value of pi. matt's suggestion of plotting the err value was crucial.

Due to the central limit theorem, the standard error will decrease proportional to `1/sqrt(N)`, with N being the sample size. This can be seen in action in my final example when `N = 500 M`. The standard error will be around `0.00005`, which implies 4 dp's of accuracy in the final result.

Reducing standard error (aka Variance reduction) is an important aspect of Monte Carlo simulation;

e.g see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction